# problem with 2 jquery autocomplete on same page

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have to 2 jquery autocomplete fields with same source url which are injected by 2 separate modules.

- When I type anything in first
  autocomplete I get result dropdown.
- Then I type something in second
  autocomplete I get result.
- But then if I type in first autocomplete, it does not show results. It makes the request etc, but it does not display result.

Code generated on the page looks like below:

```
$( '#someid1' ).autocomplete( url, {
    width: 200,
    selectFirst: false,
    minChars:1,
    matchContains: true,
    cacheLength: 1   
});

$( '#someid2' ).autocomplete( url, {
    width: 200,
    selectFirst: false,
    minChars:1,
    matchContains: true,
    cacheLength: 1   
});
```

Any help / suggestions ?-

Comment: More detail and please revise the question is worded strangely

Comment: Updated the post, hope it's more clear.

Comment: is anyone find solution for above question ... same problem with me

Answer (score 0):

not maybe the answer but did you know you can have the two selector with just one `.autocomplete()` like this,

```
$( '#someid1, #someid1' ).autocomplete( url, {
    width: 200,
    selectFirst: false,
    minChars:1,
    matchContains: true,
    cacheLength: 1   
});
```

just separate it with a comma...

Comment: Thanks, both the autocompletes are injected by separate code. So can't use above code.

Comment: Okay, so there are many things missing your question that might help us figure out what the problem is...